# PUT with an empty body using httr (on R) to webHDFS

Tags: r, hadoop, curl, hdfs, webhdfs

When trying to put to WebHDFS in order to create a file and write to it (using the following link: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html#CREATE) I run into issues using `httr`.

Using RCurl or RWebHDFS is not possible because the target Hadoop cluster is secure.

Here is the code I have attempted to use:

```
library(httr)
r <- PUT("https://hadoopmgr1p.global.ad:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser/temp/loadfile_testuser_2019-11-28_15_28_41411?op=CREATE&permission=755&user.name=testuser", 
          authenticate(":", "", type = "gssnegotiate"),
          verbose())
```

`testuser` is a super user with permissions to R/W. I get the following error:

```
<- HTTP/1.1 400 Data upload requests must have content-type set to 'application/octet-stream'
<- Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 15:42:30 GMT
<- Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 15:42:30 GMT
<- Pragma: no-cache
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<- Content-Length: 0
```

The error is pretty explanatory, so I then attempt to PUT with a content-type:

```
r <- PUT("https://hadoopmgr1p.global.ad:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser/temp/loadfile_testuser_2019-11-28_15_28_41411?op=CREATE&permission=755&user.name=testuser", 
          authenticate(":", "", type = "gssnegotiate"),
          content_type("application/octet-stream"),
          verbose())
```

I get a success - however it is not truly successful:

```
<- Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 16:04:52 GMT
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- Expires: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 16:04:52 GMT
<- Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 16:04:52 GMT
<- Pragma: no-cache
<- Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
<- Content-Length: 0
```

There is no file that was uploaded. Uploading a file with that first request, gives me another error:

```
<- HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
<- Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 16:07:24 GMT
<- Cache-Control: no-cache
<- Expires: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 16:07:24 GMT
<- Date: Fri, 29 Nov 2019 16:07:24 GMT
<- Pragma: no-cache
<- Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
<- X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
<- X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  necessary data rewind wasn't possible
```

The code in question:

```
library(httr)
temp_file <- httr::upload_file(lfs_temp_file, type = "text/plain")
r <- PUT("https://hadoopmgr1p.global.ad:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser/temp/loadfile_testuser_2019-11-28_15_28_41411?op=CREATE&permission=755&user.name=testuser", 
          authenticate(":", "", type = "gssnegotiate"),
          body=temp_file,
          content_type("application/octet-stream"),
          verbose())
```

Attempting the same command using curl works without issue:
`curl -i -k -X PUT --negotiate -u : "https://hadoopmgr1p.global.ad:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser/temp/loadfile_testuser_2019-11-28_15_28_4141?op=CREATE&permission=755&user.name=testuser"`

This results in the following:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 23:27:16 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 23:27:16 GMT
Date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 23:27:16 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate <stuff>/
Set-Cookie: hadoop.auth="<stuff>"; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: https://hadoopmgr1p.global.ad:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser/temp/loadfile_testuser_2019-11-28_15_28_4141?op=CREATE&data=true&user.name=testuser&permission=755
Content-Length: 0
```

Following the `Location` header lets us create the file successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried capturing a session with Wireshark? Comparing with the successful `curl` session might be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httr` is attempting to follow the redirect, and failing. To fix the issue, tell `httr` to stop following the location `config(followlocation = 0L)`.

The PUT command will be as follows:

```
r <- PUT("https://hadoopmgr1p.global.ad:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/testuser/temp/
          loadfile_testuser_2019-11-28_15_28_41411?op=CREATE&permission=755&user.name=testuser", 
          authenticate(":", "", type = "gssnegotiate"),
          body=NULL,
          config(followlocation = 0L),
          verbose())
```

This should return a valid reponse with a Location header.

Answer (score 1):

Good work, including the `curl` output. I believe that answers it.

Your `curl` command uses `PUT`, and your `httr` command uses `POST`. Try https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/httr/versions/1.4.1/topics/PUT .

Hint for future reference: `POST` commands are not typically used if you're specifying an exact location. That's what `PUT` is for.

Comment: Thanks Jason, that was the issue, I've updated the original question reflect the issues I was originally having.

Comment: Good luck with the next hurdle! Unfortunately, it's very hard to help further without a minimal workable example. Is it possible to set up a test Hadoop cluster people here could attempt to help you with? e.g. a small Azure / Digital Ocean / AWS machine you could destroy when finished?